# array.filter not removing value from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My action send id, text and type to my reducer but my `achievements` array remains unchanged:

```
case REMOVE_ACHIEVEMENT:
  return state.map(item => {
      if (item.id === action.id) {
          return Object.assign({}, item, {
            achievements: [
            ...item.achievements.filter(achievement => achievement !== action.id.text)
            ]
          });
      }

    return item;
});
```

[image]

Sample object:

```
  {
    date: "Sat 2nd",
    enjoyments: ['Football', 'Rugby'],
    achievements: ['Tennis', 'Football'],
    id: 1
  },
```

I would like the item `Tennis` removed from the array, any ideas?

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing what an achievement is. Is it vanilla text? Is it the same case?

Comment: might be a typo and I might have mis-seen this but, `achievement !== action.text`? Remove the `.id`?

Comment: Can you provide what your state looks like? Also, what is `action.id.text`? Can you also share the payload with the action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
case REMOVE_ACHIEVEMENT:
  return state.map(item => {
      if (item.id === action.id) {
          return Object.assign({}, item, {
            achievements: item.achievements.filter(val => val !== action.id.text)
          });
      }

    return item;
});
```

No need to use the spread operator because filter would return a new array  without the filtered items.

**Edit**
As @mhodges has pointed out the correct way to describe is `spread syntax` instead of `spread operator`.

Comment: I know this is nit-picky, but there is no spread operator. It's spread *syntax*

Comment: Thank you @mhodges. I have updated my answer with your suggestion.